# Why do I get pathauto errors when using node_save?

Tags: 7, path-aliases, nodes

When I'm programatically creating nodes using the code found [here](http://www.group42.ca/creating_and_updating_nodes_programmatically_in_drupal_7) I keep getting the following errors:

> Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in
>   pathauto_cleanstring() (line 180 of
>   .../sites/all/modules/pathauto/pathauto.inc).
>
> Warning: Illegal offset type in pathauto_cleanstring() (line 223 of
>   .../sites/all/modules/pathauto/pathauto.inc).

I have tried providing a default $node->path value, not including a value, setting the value myself using pathauto_cleanstring(), but nothing seems to work. I find it odd that I'm getting the error twice too :s

The solution to this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20519/determine-if-node-is-new/20523#20523) didn't help either unfortunately :(

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

### UPDATE:

So, the problem had to do with the data that I was using to create the path. I'm loading an XML file using simplexml_load_file. The value I was using for the node title was a SimpleXMLElement

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => Node Title
)
```

Which needed to be cast as a string before saving it as the nodes title. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Not the solution but you should try first node load and check what parameter the pathauto field needed and provide it in that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
      $path = 'your value for the path';
  $node->path = array('alias' => $path);
```

Comment: Dimitril, I'll try this again, but I'm certain I tried it in a few configurations and the problem was still present.

Comment: I did this to set the path to the correct alias...not sure if it's necessary but it works: $placeholders[t('[title]')] = pathauto_cleanstring((string)$event->title);
   $alias = pathauto_create_alias('node', 'insert', $placeholders, array('node'), $node->type);
   $node->path = array('alias' => $alias);